# SSMS 12 SP comparing int and VarChar

Tags: sql, sql-server, geocoding, ssms-2012

I have taken over a program and found that in one of my stored procedures, there is a SSIS job that fails randomly at the SP that reads the XML output of the Geocoding Service and parses the values into SQL fields, like this:

```
   INSERT #out_p_geocode_addresses
--where my following SP's are looking for the successfully geocoded addresses
(address_id int
,score int
,lat int
,lon int
,standard_address VARCHAR(max)
,geocode_match_flag bit
)

SELECT t.address_id
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),Records.Record.query('./Values/Value[sql:variable("@positionScore")]')) 
,CASE 
--Retrieves the 'Y' geocode value and sets it to the 'lat' field
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),Records.Record.query('./Values/Value[sql:variable("@positionShape")]/Y[1]'))) = 1
        THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),Records.Record.query('./Values/Value[sql:variable("@positionShape")]/Y[1]'))
END
,CASE 
--Retrieves the 'X' geocode value and sets it to the 'lon' field
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),Records.Record.query('./Values/Value[sql:variable("@positionShape")]/X[1]'))) = 1
        THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),Records.Record.query('./Values/Value[sql:variable("@positionShape")]/X[1]'))
END
--sets value for the standard_address Field
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),Records.Record.query('./Values/Value[sql:variable("@positionMatch_addr")]')) 
,CASE 
--sets the geocode_match_flag to 'Y' if the 'lon' field is numeric and not null or sets the value to 'N'
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),Records.Record.query('./Values/Value[sql:variable("@positionShape")]/X[1]'))) = 1 
        THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
ENDFROM #batch_p_geocode_addresses  AS t 
JOIN    @GeocodeResultXML.nodes('//RecordSet/Records/Record') 
                                                AS Records(Record)  
ON t.address_id = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),Records.Record.query('./Values/Value[sql:variable("@positionResultId")]'))
```

I have had an issue with this job randomly failing,and always after running the above step more than 100 times. However with the JOIN comparison, I cannot understand why it is working at all...

Could anyone explain why this comparison is working, or why it could be randomly failing when calling this SP?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Some records failing while most succeed is almost always bad (or unexpected, at least) data in the source.

If using SQL 2012 or newer, I'd recommend switching the CONVERT to TRY_CONVERT.  A bad value on CONVERT gives an error.  A bad value on TRY_CONVERT yields a NULL result which you can then deal with.

You should also look into TRY CATCH notation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql) which will allow you to get specifics on the error that should help in troubleshooting.

Comment: I am using a Try/Catch block to call the SP above, but i will look into TRY-CONVERT.. I kinda havent heard of it so i am eager to see how it works